# PowerShell get users from Deny log on locally policy

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to receive users that are present in "Deny log on locally" policy with PowerShell v2? I thought that it was possible with Get-GPO but I can't figure out how.

Get-GPO: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461059.aspx

Deny log on locally: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221948.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

```
$ad_deny_logon = `
    (Get-WmiObject -Class RSOP_UserPrivilegeRight -Namespace root\rsop\computer | `
        Where-Object{
            $_.UserRight -eq "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight" -and 
            $_.precedence -eq 1
        }
    ) | `
        sort -Unique | `
            Select-Object @{Name="User & Groups";Expression={$_.AccountList}}, @{Name="Computer name";Expression={$_.PSComputerName}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but should work:

- Export the GPO (path must already exist):

  ```
  Export-GPO -Name 'policy_name' -Path 'C:\some\folder'
  ```
- Find the file `GptTmpl.inf` and select the line with the desired privilege from its content:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' -Filter 'gpttmpl.inf' -Recurse |
    Get-Content |
    Where-Object { $_ -like 'SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight*' }
  ```
- Extract the SIDs from the line:

  ```
  ... -replace '^.* = ' -replace '\*' -split ','
  ```
- Convert the SIDs back to user/group names:

  ```
  $acct = [wmi]"Win32_Sid.SID='$sid'"
  '{0}\{1}' -f $acct.ReferencedDomainName, $acct.AccountName
  ```
- Clean up.

Comment: You are using the Name property with Export-GPO but is that the same property as in Get-GPO? Because if I return all policies with Get-GPO -All it will only return two policies Default Domain Policy and Default Domain Controllers Policy. So the Deny log on locally policy is not present in the output. Both policies have User values represented by Microsoft.GroupPolicy.UserConfiguration value.

Comment: Yes, name is name. If you don't get a result either the setting isn't defined or you have a mistake somewhere. Also, privileges can only be assigned via machine policy, not via user policy.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I'll have to check with others if this will do and if so I'll mark it as the answer later today.